# docker-compose: use file from volume in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I defined a volume in my docker-compose.yml. I want to use one of these files from the volume in my Dockerfile, but I get the error: "No such file or directory"

If I create the container without the access to the files in the Dockerfile I will see all files from the volume inside the container at the specific location from the docker-compose.yml file.

Is this how it should work or do I something wrong? I think I am missing something.

repository: https://github.com/Lightshadow244/OwnMusicWeb

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ownmusicweb:
   build: .
   container_name: ownmusicweb
   hostname: ownmusicweb
   volumes:
       - ~/OwnMusicWeb/ownmusicweb:/ownmusicweb
   ports:
    - 83:8000
   tty: true
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /ownmusicweb
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "python-pip"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "Django", "eyeD3", "djangorestframework", "markdown", "django-filter"]
RUN ["python", "/ownmusicweb/manage.py", "migrate"]
RUN ["python", "/ownmusicweb/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Did you try to use an absolute path instead of shortcut of home directory?
~/OwnMusicWeb/ownmusicweb:/ownmusicweb

Comment: Try also to use ADD directive before doing RUN ["python", "/ownmusicweb/manage.py", "migrate"]

Comment: @Innuendo i tried it with the absolut path but i got the same error. I dont want to use ADD because then it will just copy the files and i have to rebuild the image every time i change the files

Comment: Ok, to prevent the rebuild on every launch I see two ways to solve it: the first is to add a "command" directive to your docker-compose.yml and to move there the part of migrate and runserver, this should work. Another way (which I like less) is to use ENTRYPOINT directive, the idea here is create a .sh file with commands to migrate and runserver, this one you should ADD to dockerfile, and from the script you can launcn any file from the volume.

Comment: @Innuendo Now i use the entrypoint to do my things and it worked. So the command RUN in Dockefile is working befor the volumes are mounted? Thanky very much

Comment: Yes, RUN is launched at the build level, when container does not exist yet. I put a little summary in the answer. This is just my vision of the solution, I don't know if this is the best approach, so maybe a better answer will arrive from people more experienced here.

Answer (score 5):

Summarising discussion in comments:

**RUN** directive has no access to volume because it's not mounted yet. Docker creates [build context](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#general-guidelines-and-recommendations) only, which is neccessary to use ADD directive. But in this way the files will remain in the compiled container so you will need a rebuild to update those.

After build is finished, triggered by **"build: ."** in docker-compose.yml, docker launches the container and adds a volume. But it's too late in your case.

Suggested mechanism is to use **ENTRYPOINT** with a scipt which launches your stuff. It's being executed after the build in the phase of launch, so you'll have access to the volume.

Another approach, which seems to me a bit cleaner is to use **command** directive of docker-compose. You can put the same script inside. It depends of the way you're doing deployment and the way you're using docker in the development environment.